# Local variable storage on memory in C

Tags: c, memory, stack, stack-overflow

These days I am reading a document about stack overflow and found one sentence confused me.

> Items that are pushed on the stack can, incidentally, only be put at  word boundaries, 
>   meaning that the address must be  a multiple of the word length. Hence if the program 
>   contains a local variable using only one byte, then nevertheless a full word is used to store 
>   this variable!

Does it means that a short int(2 bytes) local variable which is stored on stack of 32-bits machine will waste 2 bytes since the system will assign a full word to store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's what it means. It depends on the system implementation and addressing implementation, but its pretty common to have word alignment.

Comment: so does it means that we can not save space by using data type with bits less than 32?

Comment: @JustForTest depending on your system, in many cases - yes, that's what it means. You can use "packed" structures though, but be careful when directly accessing the data in those.